# cant print 2d array with format method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, 2d

I can't print the data present in my 2d list.

I can print the data present in 1d list , but I can't print data present in 2d list.

code for 1d array:

```
l=['x',25,6.2]
t='hello my name is {0[0]},and i am {0[1]},i am {0[2]} feet '.format(l)
print(t)

OP:hello my name is x,and i am 25,i am 6.2 feet
```

code for 2d array:

```
l= [['x',25,6.2]
    ,[2,2,2]]
t= 'hello my name is {[0][0]},and i am {[0][1]},i am {[1][2]} feet '.format(l)
print(t)
```

OP:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    t= 'hello my name is {[0][0]},and i am {[0][1]},i am {[1][2]} feet '.format(l)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the index of the placeholder (`0`, that is) in your attempt for the 2-D list:

```
l= [['x',25,6.2]
    ,[2,2,2]]
t= 'hello my name is {0[0][0]},and i am {0[0][1]},i am {0[1][2]} feet '.format(l)
print(t)
```

Comment: thank you...what is the purpose of first '0' used while marking index in {0[0][0]},(the first zero)?

Comment: You're welcome. `0` refers to the index of the argument passed to the `format` method. Since there's only one argument in this case, `0` refers to the first and only argument, `l`. Please refer to `element_index` in [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for more details.

Comment: Also, can you accept this answer if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)